# Objective C -- passing array literal to a method

Tags: objective-c

This seems to work (compiler doesn't complain, anyway):

```
float adsr[4] = {0,1.0/PULSE_SPEED, 0,1};
[sequence setBaseADSR:adsr];
```

but I want to make it more concise and do this:

```
[sequence setBaseADSR:{0,1.0/PULSE_SPEED, 0,1}];
```

How do I do it? In javascript, I'd call stuff in the brackets an "array literal". Not sure if C languages have the same concept or terminology though.

Comment: If you have control over this API, I would strongly recommend not passing around raw arrays like that. C arrays are messy and fiddly.

Comment: @Chuck what would you suggest instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second way does not work because the compiler does not know which type the array elements are. However, this or something like this should work:

```
[sequence setBaseADSR:(float adsr[4] = {0,1.0/PULSE_SPEED, 0,1})];
```

as a declaration returns the leftmost element in the expression (cannot test it right now though)

Comment: indeed. But is the same way we initialize counters in for loops, so for throwaway purposes, it suffices

Comment: Totally unnecessary. See Cirno de Bergerac's answer.

Comment: can you post a link to Cimo's answer? can't see it here

Answer (score 11):

If your compiler supports the C99 compound literal syntax, it's possible.

```
[sequence setBaseADRS:(float [4]){0,1.0/PULSE_SPEED,0,1}];
```

Comment: One of my favorite features. I do this a lot for `CGPoint`, `CGRect`, `UIEdgeInsets`, etc: `(CGRect){{x, y), {w, h}}`